# Can you rename a shell session by command in linux?

Tags: linux, shell, session, kde-plasma

I like to keep my shell sessions named with useful titles as I work, this helps me keep track of what I'm using each of the many tabs for.

Currently to rename a session I double click its name on the tabbed part of the console - is there any command that I can use to do this from within the shell? It would save me a bit of time.

thanks in advance

edit :-
I am using KDE's Konsole shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Currently to rename a session I double click its name on the tabbed part of the console

This sounds like you're using KDE's Konsole.  Is this true?

If so, in KDE 3:

```
dcop $KONSOLE_DCOP_SESSION renameSession "I am renamed!"
```

In KDE 4, the old DCOP interfaces haven't been ported over to the new D-BUS IPC yet, but you can change the settings for tabnames to follow the window name set by each screen, and set the window name as described by the other answers.

Answer (score 5):

The article [How to change the title of an xterm](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/Xterm-Title.html) should help.

Comment: I've managed to change the title of the command line using a method suggested in here, however it doesn't change the title of the tab for the session at the bottom of the terminal. Any ideas how to do this would be great.

Comment: I suppose the method to change the title of the tab would be specific to whatever terminal program you're using.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this page](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/Xterm-Title.html), you should be able to use something like this:

```
echo -n "\033]0;New Window Title\007"
```

I'm not in Linux at the moment, so this is untested. I do know that it is possible to change the window title under program control, so this seems likely to work.

Comment: This might look cleaner: `printf "\033]0;%s\007\n" "New Window Title"`

Answer (score 2):

For /usr/bin/konsole
you can change the title of a konsole terminal from the menu:
Settings->Edit Current Profile->Tabs

edit "Tab title format" to be whatever you want.  After interacting with the shell, the title will reset to what you put.

for /usr/bin/xterm running in xorg-server 2:1.10.1-1ubuntu1

echo -ne "\033]0;My Fun X-Terminal\007"

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this really depends on the terminal program you're using.

However, I'll just assume it's sensible, and emulates an xterm enough that it respects xterm escape codes - in which case, you probably want to look here : http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/Xterm-Title.html#s3

Note: unwind's example below requires echo to be called like this "echo -ne", otherwise the '\' characters are echoed literally.

Answer (score 1):

For the default terminal on Ubuntu (I'm still on 10.04) try **xtitle**.

```
$> sudo apt-get install xtitle
   ...
$> xtitle --title wow it worked!
   or simply
$> xtitle this is great
```